# ValueError: Could not interpret input 'Comfort Important'

Tags: python

```
# reshape the d dataframe suitable for statsmodels package 
df_melt = pd.melt(df.reset_index(), id_vars=['Sleep Subject'], value_vars=['Sleep Subject', 'Comfort Important', 'Quality Important', 'Comfort vs Price', 'Quality vs Price', 'Improve Sleep vs Price', 'Sleep Cooler vs Price', 'Warranty', 'Try before Buy', 'Buy Online', 'Online Uncomfortable', 'Online Quality'])

# generate a boxplot to see the data distribution by Sleep Subject. Using boxplot, we can 
# easily detect the differences between different Sleep Subject
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns
ax = sns.boxplot(x='Comfort Important', y='Comfort vs Price', data=df_melt, color='#99c2a2')
ax = sns.swarmplot(x="Comfort Important", y="Comfort vs Price", data=df_melt, color='#7d0013')
plt.show()
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
~\AppData\Local\Temp/ipykernel_16856/1928408842.py in <module>
      6 import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
      7 import seaborn as sns
----> 8 ax = sns.boxplot(x='Comfort Important', y='Comfort vs Price', data=df_melt, color='#99c2a2')
      9 ax = sns.swarmplot(x="Comfort Important", y="Comfort vs Price", data=df_melt, color='#7d0013')
     10 plt.show()

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\seaborn\categorical.py in boxplot(x, y, hue, data, order, hue_order, orient, color, palette, saturation, width, dodge, fliersize, linewidth, whis, ax, **kwargs)
   2233     plotter = _BoxPlotter(x, y, hue, data, order, hue_order,
   2234                           orient, color, palette, saturation,
-> 2235                           width, dodge, fliersize, linewidth)
   2236 
   2237     if ax is None:

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\seaborn\categorical.py in __init__(self, x, y, hue, data, order, hue_order, orient, color, palette, saturation, width, dodge, fliersize, linewidth)
    434                  width, dodge, fliersize, linewidth):
    435 
--> 436         self.establish_variables(x, y, hue, data, orient, order, hue_order)
    437         self.establish_colors(color, palette, saturation)
    438 

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\seaborn\categorical.py in establish_variables(self, x, y, hue, data, orient, order, hue_order, units)
    150                 if isinstance(var, str):
    151                     err = "Could not interpret input '{}'".format(var)
--> 152                     raise ValueError(err)
    153 
    154             # Figure out the plotting orientation

ValueError: Could not interpret input 'Comfort Important'
```

I am having issues with seaborn I think. I could appreciate some help with troubleshooting. It seems to be an issue with line 8 and 9. I am using a rather large dataset so that could be an issue with data visualization.

Comment: As you see at the error message end, checking whether variable extracted is type of **str**, if so, it raises ValueError. Perhaps data your trying to plot is **str** type somewhere?

Comment: I checked my data, I don't see anything resembling a string. They are all values.

Comment: Well, a string is a value too. Could you post the output of `df_melt['Comfort Important'].describe()`?

Comment: I resolved the issue. I didn't need pd.melt as my index was fine as it is.